# How do we or can we use node modules via npm with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, meteor

How do we or can we use node modules via npm with [Meteor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_%28platform%29)?

Or is that something that will be dependent on the packaging [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)?

Or is there a prescribed method that is recommended?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> [Meteor 1.3](http://info.meteor.com/blog/announcing-meteor-1.3), released on March 28, 2016, gives apps full ES6 (ES2015) modules support and out of the box NPM support. Apps and packages can now load NPM modules directly and easily on the client and on the server.

If you can use 1.3, then check http://guide.meteor.com/using-packages.html#installing-npm.

For example, to use moment.js:

```
meteor npm install --save moment
```

Then in your code:

```
import moment from 'moment';

// this is equivalent to the standard node require:
const moment = require('moment');
```

If you need to use an older version of Meteor, read the rest of the answer below.

---

**Pre-Meteor 1.3**:

[Since v0.6.0, Meteor integrates directly with NPM modules](http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/04/04/meteor-060-brand-new-distribution-system-app-packages-npm-integration) with the help of a 3rd party package. For example, to use a module like [`ws`](https://npmjs.org/package/ws),

1. Run `sudo npm install -g ws` (or for local installs, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587964/where-do-we-put-node-modules-we-install-by-npm-in-a-meteor-project))
2. In your sever JavaScript file,

   ```
   var Websocket = Npm.require('ws');
   var myws = new Websocket('url');
   ```

To use a core Node module, just make the corresponding `Npm.require()` call, e.g. `var Readable = Npm.require('stream').Readable`.

---

You can use any of the more than [230,000 NPM modules](https://www.npmjs.com/) directly with Meteor thanks to the [NPM package](http://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor.html) developed by Arunoda.

You can also define dependencies on Npm packages from smart packages - from [the initial announcement](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/b6zQrgk8lYo/7KykCwz19WMJ) of npm support:

Your smart package can now define dependencies directly, by adding a call to `Npm.depends` in `package.js`:

```
Npm.depends({
  "awssum": "0.12.2",
  "underscore.string": "2.3.1"
});
```

All of this works well with hot code reload, just like the rest of Meteor. When you make changes, the bundler will automatically download missing npm packages and re-pin its dependencies.

To use an NPM module within server code, use `Npm.require` as you would normally use plain `require`. Notably, `__meteor_bootstrap__.require` has been eliminated and all of its uses have been converted to `Npm.require`.

There is [a small example of using an NPM module in your application](https://github.com/avital/meteor-xml2js-npm-demo).

Comment: any idea when 0.6 will be released for windows?

Comment: Can you clarify that Npm.require(...) works with nodejs core modules like http or url ? maybe add such information to the answer if you have it.

Comment: @MikeGraf: added an example of using a core module.

Comment: @rickyduck: [Meteor for Windows](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows) is very much usable right now, and will be officially released in a few days, if not today.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Finally!

Comment: Do you have to import the package in every file you want to use it in or just once for the project?

Answer (score 21):

> Note that this answer applies to versions of Meteor prior to 0.6.0, which was released in April 2013 and added direct `npm` integration

Install modules as you normally would through `npm` and then use

```
var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require,
    pd = require("pd"),
    after = require("after") // etc
```

Load any modules you want

Comment: @SteeveCannon it goes in an if server statement as it will fail on the client

Comment: when you install a module with npm, check that the npm version is 1.0 or greater and do a local install (npm install module_name).

Comment: And how to require a module on the client? Just trying to get https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node working

Comment: @Nico use browserify or hack the module into a single js file

Comment: it seems to crash on transitive dependencies - try using aws-lib for example. Any ideas?

Comment: @Joscha - Maybe this can help, https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/381 -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693113/dependencies-between-javascript-files-in-meteor

Comment: You're doing Require but where do you install modules ?

Answer (score 6):

I did a complete write-up on this on Meteorpedia:

http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/npm

The article covers how to use npm in both your app and/or packages, and common patterns for wrapping regular callbacks and event emmitter callbacks to work properly in Meteor and Fibers, and include's references to Arunoda's async-utilities and additional resources.

Comment: "NPM in your App" point 3 . var Github = Meteor.require('github'); Should it not be Meteor.npmRequire ( ... ) ?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [Meteor Npm](http://atmospherejs.com/package/npm) package

```
meteor add meteorhacks:npm
```

Then create a `packages.json` file in your project's root directory with the NPM module's info.

```
{
    "redis": "0.8.2",
     "github": "0.1.8"
}
```

Then as simple as (server side)

```
var github = Meteor.npmRequire("github");
var redis = Meteor.npmRequire("redis");
```

So you just use `Meteor.npmRequire` instead of `require`

Comment: that package is overkill just for simply using npm modules.

Comment: @MurWade its the easiest way to do it. The only other way is to make your own package, which is overkill. I also don't recommend using `npm install -g` as in Dan's answer because the app won't work properly when bundled/deployed. This way has it installed when its bundled too

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Gist on how to do this as of Meteor 0.6.5, *[How to add Node.js npms to your Meteor.js project](https://gist.github.com/kenyee/6307258)*.

Answer (score -1):

I am using [such a script](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-pdf.js/blob/dd85c069e5d94a12f0a2e55ffa29e8b566e62d0b/bootstrap.coffee) which nicely install all [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) dependencies. It behaves similar to the official support in the Meteor engine branch (it installs dependencies at runtime), but it also supports installing from [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) repositories and similar goodies.

Comment: Meteor 0.6.0 replaces the need for such scripts. See Dan's answer.