# How to use npm module in Meteor client?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm thoroughly confused on how to use an npm module in Meteor client code.

I understand modules like fs would only work server-side, but in this case I'd like to use a simple text module like this for displaying pretty dates:

https://github.com/ecto/node-timeago

I've tried installing the module under /public/node_modules,
and it works great on the server-side following these instructions from SO: (
[How do we or can we use node modules via npm with Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165978/how-do-we-or-can-we-use-node-modules-via-npm-with-meteor))

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require
  var timeago = require('timeago')
  console.log(timeago(new Date()))
  ...
```

However it doesn't work in the client-side code:

```
if (Meteor.is_client) {
  var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require
  var timeago = require('timeago')
  console.log(timeago(new Date()))
  ...

Uncaught ReferenceError: __meteor_bootstrap__ is not defined"
```

Server-side is sort of useless for me in this case, as I'm trying to render text on the client.

Comment: The method in http://stackoverflow.com/q/17068813/586086 works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe you need to use the server side version.  Use the npm stuff for server side only and btw, put it in your /public/ as well.  Who knows maybe you can call it once it is in your /public/, try it.  Or try this.

Use something like the jquery timeago.js

Put it in /client/ or something like /client/js

Create a /client/helpers.js or some such.

Use a handlebars helper.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('date', function(date) {
  if(date) {
    dateObj = new Date(date);
    return $.timeago(dateObj);
  }
  return 'a long long time ago in a galaxy far away';
});
```

Example of calling 'date' handlebars helper function from template.

```
{{ date created }}
```

Where date is the handebars helper and created is the date coming out of the meteor/mongo collection.

See the github Britto project.  That is where I got this code snippet and used it in a chat room app I wrote.  Works fine.

There are a couple of others floating out there.  Go to madewith.meteor.com and peruse the source of some of the projects.

Comment: Thanks mate!   So a summary of issue is:
* npm modules aren't optimal for client side
* Handlebar helpers are your friend
* jQuery plugins can be used and referenced automatically if they are in the app dir

Comment: Correction "app /client dir" - as you will see "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" otherwise.

Comment: yeah, it is working for  me, I used the Britto example from JonathanKingston's code...there is another project that has a good human readable date too...search through the maddewith.meteor.com projects

Comment: @7zark7 You should try the an npm install in your /public/ directory though if you want to use node modules.  I wasn't sure if I was clear about that part.

Comment: @SteeveCannon, I suggest a package.json with your node module dependencies specified, and a scripts.install to move the node_modules folder into public/ after those deps are installed. I've written an example project, which will also deploy to Heroku: https://github.com/matb33/heroku-meteor-npm.