# upload video to youtube in meteor

Tags: javascript, file-upload, meteor, youtube, youtube-api

I'm planning to use this node module to upload video to youtube

```
https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/
```

I'm getting value from file input like

```
 var files = $("input.file_bag")[0].files;
```

As we can use node modules only on server side as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17069287/3248794

how to send the data to meteor server and then from there to youtube api.

my questions

```
1) How to send video file(data) to server side?
2) Is it the effiecient way of passing data to `client->server->youtube`, Is there any alternatives for this?
```

if you know answer to any question post it,highly appreciated

**Edit**

or

can I send post request to youtube from client? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

If so how to pass accesstoken with this request?

Comment: Meteor.call('upload', files); and then in Meteor.methods do what you wanted to do, you can use npm there

Comment: I created a gist to demonstrate uploading a video from Meteor server-side. https://gist.github.com/bobbigmac/18fbd1395817434b207c54eba86608e1