# File load order in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have defined some functions in `server/methods.js` which I use in some of my methods such as:

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

If I want to use the functions in my methods, I have to place them in `server/methods.js`. Why can't I place the functions in `lib/utils.js`? I thought that files in `lib/` would be called first, so functions there would be accessible in all other files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the order in which Meteor loads Javascript files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693113/how-do-i-change-the-order-in-which-meteor-loads-javascript-files)

Comment: typo between `lib` and `libs`?

Comment: Sorry, it is `lib`. Just a typo in this question

Comment: The answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693113/how-do-i-change-the-order-in-which-meteor-loads-javascript-files says that files in `lib` will be loaded first, but it's not the case here. Maybe I can't use 'publicly defined' UDFs inside server methods? and is it correct to only define methods on the server?

Comment: what happens when you place your function inside `lib/utils.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining your function like this `function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {...}` its availability will actually be limited to the **lib/utils.js** file and your function won't be available from any other JS files on the server.

You have to declare your function like this in order to put it in the global scope and make it accessible from other JS files:

```
randomIntFromInterval = function (min, max) {
  ...
};
```

Note the absence of the `var` keyword which would also limit the function availability to the **lib/utils.js** file.