# How to organize folders and files on Meteor project?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to understand Meteor as I create a project and I find some things a little difficult to understand so far.

1- When they say I can create a `server` and a `client` folder, where exactly I am meant to do so? Sibling of `.meteor` ? And will everything be at client's or server's scope when the app starts or do I have to do something else? If I create a `foo.js` and a `foo` function inside it in `client` folder, can I just call `foo()` in `Meteor.isClient` and it will work?

2- I need to create an upload folder so people can upload their stuff (images). So where am I supposed to do this? Plus, how can I get the absolute path to my project and find this `upload` folder inside?

During my attempts I tried the following:

```
fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');
__ROOT_APP_PATH__ = fs.realpathSync('.');
```

But `__ROOT_APP_PATH__` is `.meteor\local\build\programs\server`. Quite hidden right?!

3- I saw some people uploading and saving files on MongoDB directly. This is something we usually don't do with relational databases. We move the file to a known folder on a CDN or on our own disk and save the hash or name of that file so we can easily find it. Isn't it encouraged with Meteor + MongoDB? Why would I save the file itself on Mongo instead of moving it to a folder?

Answer (score 3):

not any specific way to do but meteor recommend it doing this way
http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/filestructure

Comment: I created a JS file in the root folder, declared a function and called it when client is started. Says it is undefined

Answer (score 3):

**FOLDER STRUCTURE:**

```
both/ (OR lib/)          -- common code for server and client
  |- collections/        -- declare collections (e.g Employer = new Meteor.Collection("employer");)
  |- router     /        -- router code(e.g Router.route(..))

client/                  -- client side code
  |- global/             -- all global variable for client
  |- helpers/            -- global helper for client (for all templates)
  |- plugins/            -- all the plugins code(if you use any)
  |- stylesheets/        -- css / less files
  |- templates/          -- all templates
        |- home.html     -- home template(html)
        |- home.js       -- home template(js)

public/                  -- images/icons/fonts (meteor looking at this file)

server/                  -- server code
  |- methods/            -- server methods/API (e.g Meteor.methods({...}))
  |- publish/            -- publish code from server
```

this is the basic folder structure  for meteor project which i follow. For further [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122977/what-are-the-best-practices-for-structuring-a-large-meteor-app-with-many-html-te) or [Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp). For any question feel free ask in comments..

Comment: I created a folder called `lib`, inside it I put a JS file and declared `foo`. When I call it on `Meteor.isClient`, it says "foo is undefined"

Comment: `lib` or `both` are similar and it the parent most directory..i mean sibling of `.meteor`..it is common code for meteor server and client. And i important thing it get executed before `client` and `server`. If you following folder structure and the code which you in client directory is taken as client code. So, no need to put use `Meteor.isClient` again.

Comment: I mean I created `function foo(){}` inside `foo.js` in `/client` sibling of `.meteor` and called `foo()`  on my main file, inside `Meteor.isClient` with the rest of the code. It says "foo is undefined"

Comment: i am assuming your  `function foo(){}` is a global function in another file and you calling it from other. i also sometime faced same issue on same. if you doing so put it in same file and check once...let us know.

Comment: Meteor wrap all files in function expressions, anything declared in a file with `var` or like this `function name()` will be scoped to the file only. You must declare it globally so Meteor export it, see my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427322/file-load-order-in-meteor/31430986#31430986

Comment: You should export global variables via packaging - just create local package and add it into meteor project