# Meteor - accessing method from Lib folder

Tags: javascript, methods, meteor

I want to access methods related to modal in another js file. So I created a global object called app and created methods like so:

```
//global variables    
app = {};

//modal components
app.modal = function ( ele ) {
  return {
    "closeModal": function() {
      $('.modal.fade').removeClass("in");
      $(".browser .overlay").removeClass("show");
    }
  }
}();
```

Then to access the closeModal method, I basically call `app.modal.closeModal()` in a *.js file. But I am getting the following error message:

```
Exception in setTimeout callback: TypeError: app.modal.closeModal is not a function
```

I have been staring at this for a while but cannot seem to see where the issue is. I bet I am doing something really stupid.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`app.modal` is defined as a function, not as an object, so you would have to write `app.modal().closeModal()`.

But you should define modal as an object like this :

```
app = {
  modal: {
    closeModal: function(){
      // whatever
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested but I still seem to get the following error : Exception in setTimeout callback: TypeError: app.modal.closeModal is not a function...

Answer (score 0):

As saimeunt stated, you probably want to use something like:

```
app = {};

app.modal = {
  closeModal: function() {
    $('.modal.fade').removeClass("in");
    $(".browser .overlay").removeClass("show");
  }
};
```

Also, you'll need to place this file (containing `#closeModal`) in a location that will be loaded before the file that calls it is loaded. This is assuming that you're calling it automatically (appears that you are from within a setTimeout()).

For details on loading order, see the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741082/4044373.