# How to use profilers with Meteor?

Tags: node.js, profiling, profiler, meteor

My Meteor application, in server side (node process), is using much more CPU than would be acceptable, and I want to investigate it.

Two simultaneous clients are leading node to use 100% of CPU.
It is probably related to a massive use of *observers*, but I need to investigate it further before changing the whole application.

So, what tool can I use to profile it? How to use it?

Comment: `console.time('some identifier'); //run a function here; console.timeEnd('some identifier');` Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[APM, Application Performance Monitoring](http://meteorapm.com), is a Meteor [package](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-apm-client) + cloud service developed by [Arunoda Susiripala](http://arunoda.me/) of MeteorHacks fame. It's in beta right now, and it looks very promising:

[image: calls]

From the Costly Calls tab, you can drill into methods and identify those that take longest:

[image: screenshot]

This 1-minute [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDEMvqbefI4) shows just this [identification of costly methods](http://support.meteorapm.com/knowledgebase/articles/308661-identify-method-wait-time-and-fix-it), which is probably  what you want.

#### More screenshots

[image: more screenshots]

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I found is [v8-profiler](https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler#readme) (plus [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector)).

## Install

1. Go to `[Meteor installation folder]/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules`.
2. exec `$ npm install v8-profiler` there.
3. Add in your server code:

```js
Meteor.startup(function() {
  profiler = __meteor_bootstrap__.require("v8-profiler")
  Meteor._debug("Server started!");
});
```

- this method will be [replaced soon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15351543/599991)

## Use

- Wherever in your app server code you can profile this way:

  ```
  profiler.startProfiling("name");                   //begin cpu profiling
  yourCode();
  var cpuProfile = profiler.stopProfiling("name");   //finish cpu profiling
  ```
- Do not forget to run `node-inspector`

Comment: Would this show a breakdown per method, as in [this output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19467545/1269037) ?

Answer (score 3):

You should also take a look at the Meteor-specific [Observatory](http://observatoryjs.com/). It's a powerful server- and client-side logging package, with profiling support for arbitrary functions, and "automagical logging of template lifecycle methods, Collection methods (only find is supported so far), and Subscriptions profiling".

Comment: It sounds a great and beauty logger with something else, but I haven't found profiling capabilities. They just *plan to add other useful objects monitoring, e.g., users once auth is finished, and likely something around Collections as well.*.

Comment: This is awesome if you want to profile DDP.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[NodeTime](https://nodetime.com/) is a pretty awesome profiling service.  It's free to use, which is especially helpful in situations like yours, and is super easy to set-up!

Comment: same error:
`Error: Cannot find module 'nodetime'`

It says to
`Add before any other require statement in your application, e.g. at the first line of main module.`

So, where should I put it?

Comment: I added the require statement in the first line of *Meteor/app/meteor/run.js*, and there are a lot of other requires after that, but **nodetime** is not found.
It sounds a importing problem, that may be caused by *Meteorite*.

Comment: I found it! The problem is that meteor, in some cases, doesn't share libraries with system, so you should copy new files to *Meteor/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/nodetime*. Take a look at *admin/generate-dev-bundle.sh* to see it in action.

Answer (score 2):

There's now

`console.time('myFunction');
myFunction();
console.timeEnd('myFunction')
//Outputs: myFunction: xxxxms`

which I just verified that it works using Meteor 1.2.  Super simple, easy, and built-in.

Comment: Nice hint, and it's not meteor specific. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console