# Meteor Node Process CPU Usage Nears 100%

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm having trouble with my Meteor app when it gets to its peak amount of traffic (peak for this is nothing, 1k visits, maybe 2,500 pageviews in a day). CPU usage spikes and never recovers, so I've taken to using Nodetime to monitor usage and I've been reloading the process (`forever restart`) to get things back to normal.

I'm fairly new to profiling, so finding the underlying cause has me at a loss for where to start. I'm fairly certain it has to do with my app's server code, but the profiling seems to point to the Fibers module as a "hotspot" which I understand aids in making my server code synchronous.

Below is a snippet from the profiling results. I hope someone can guide me in the right direction in troubleshooting this!

[image]

Comment: Lol at promise implementation being a hot spot

Answer (score 33, accepted):

While I don't have a specific answer to your question, I have experience dealing with CPU issues for our production meteor app for so I can give you a list of things to investigate.

1. Upgrade to the latest version of meteor and the appropriate node version (see the [changelog](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md)). As of this writing that's meteor 0.8.2 and node 0.10.28.
2. Read [this](http://projectricochet.com/blog/meteor-js-performance) and [this](http://projectricochet.com/blog/things-you-need-know-when-scaling-meteor-js) article. The latter makes a great point that you really should always try to delay activation of subscriptions until you need them. In particular you may not need to publish anything for users who are not logged in. In my experience, meteor CPU problems have everything to do with subscriptions.
3. Be careful with `observe` and `observeChanges`. These are **expensive** and are easy to abuse. In particular:

   - Make sure you are calling `stop()` on your handles when they are no longer needed (consider using a package like [publish-with-relations](https://github.com/erundook/meteor-publish-with-relations) so this is done for you).
   - Fetch only the collections and fields that you absolutely need. Observe works by continually diffing objects (requires lots of CPU). The fewer and smaller objects you have, the less there is to compute.
4. <s>Consider using [smart-collections](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-smart-collections) before it is [retired](http://meteorhacks.com/retiring-smart-collections.html).</s>  Use [oplog tailing](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver) - this can make for a night and day difference in performance and CPU usage in your app.
5. Consider making some things not reactive (also mentioned in the articles above). For us that was a big win. We had one extremely expensive join that was used on two frequently accessed pages on the site. When it got to the point where the CPU was pegged at 100% about every 30 minutes I gave up on reactivity for that element and just did the join on the server and shipped the data to the client via a method call. I also created a server-side expiring cache for these results and stored them by user (special thanks to Matt DeBergalis for this suggestion).
6. Do a preventative nightly restart. I have a cron job that tells `forever` to restart our app once a day in the middle of the night. That brings the CPU down from ~10% to 1%. This seems like black magic, but the fact that the CPU usage changes after a reset leads me to believe this is a good idea.

#### Updated thoughts (1/13/14)

- We migrated to [oplog tailing](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver) as soon as it was available (meteor 0.7) and that made a big difference. Note that in order to get access to the oplog, you'll probably need to either host your own db or run a dedicated instance on the hosting provider of your choice. I'd also recommend adding the [`facts`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver#wiki-how-to-tell-if-your-queries-are-using-oplogobservedriver) package to actually tell if its working.
- There was a memory leak discovered in `publish-with-relations`, and as of this writing the atmosphere version (v0.1.5) hasn't been bumped to reflect these changes. If you are using it in production, I strongly recommend checking out the HEAD version and running it [locally](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages).
- We stopped doing nightly restarts a couple of weeks ago. So far everything has been fine (fingers crossed).

#### Updated thoughts (7/2/14)

- A few months ago we switched over to using an Elastic Deployment on [mongohq](https://www.mongohq.com/pricing/). It's affordable, the performance has been great, and they even have a [blog post](http://blog.mongohq.com/meteor-the-oplog-and-elastic-deployment/) which tells you how to enable oplog tailing.
- I'd strongly recommend checking out [kadira](https://kadira.io/) to help diagnose performance issues in your app. Also check out the [academy articles](https://kadira.io/academy/) which have a number of good tips in them.

Comment: Excellent answer!  Particularly want to highlight #4. Meteor core will have oplog tailing sometime soon but in the meantime SmartCollections seems like a good alternative.  You'll need access to the oplog though so you'll probably need to host your own mongodb.

Comment: Thanks David, I can certainly see where my pub/sub setup could be the driving factor looking solely at traffic patterns. This is a great starting point. I'll report back if I find a more specific resolution in the process.

Comment: @alanning Thanks! I'm excited to see the oplog optimizations get integrated into core. Unfortunately, for those of us who don't host our own DB, access to an oplog seems to require a dedicated plan on mongohq or mongolab ($).

Comment: @WesJohnson Glad to be of help! :) I'm very interested to find out what worked for you.

Comment: Fantastic answer. I have also been having this problem.

Comment: Also watch for memory usage. I notice my app memory increases overtime. Reboot is helping with this problem.

Comment: Nice Post - thanks for your time. Have the same problem and now I will fix as much as i can dependings on your post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also having this problem. Actually there is an [issue with 0.6.6.1](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1506), I run `meteor --release 0.6.6` and the cpu is back to normal now.

Comment: Interesting, although this appears to be specific to OS X, so I assume this isn't affecting anyone in production.

Comment: @DavidWeldon I'm running meteor on a virtualbox with debian 7.1. My app isn't in production yet :(

Comment: Well that's a bummer. In my experience, file watching has never worked quite right via the node core api. I have always used an npm module for it - maybe the meteor team should consider that as well.