# How to debug slow meteor methods?

Tags: meteor

A number of my meteor methods have mysteriously slowed down recently. Whereas they used to be quite snappy, many are taking 10 or so seconds.

Things not causing the slowdown:

- Additional functionality, the slowed sections of the codebase haven't been changed significantly
- Machine load (cpu load hovering around 30%)
- Additional DB load (no new queries added)
- transfer time of the return data (returns undefined)
- blocking method (I've tried with this.unblock() within the method)

I did debugging by using console.time() / console.timeEnd() on both the server and client side. The server side code takes about .3 seconds to run, but the client doesnt get the callback until about 11 seconds after the meteor.call() ...

This is the server method:

```
function cancelSomething(somethingId, reason) {
  console.time('cancelSomething method');
  check(somethingId, String);
  check(reason, String);

  if (!AuthChecks()))
    throw new Meteor.Error(401, 'Not Authorized');

  var something = MySomethings.findOne({'_id': somethingId});
  if (!something)
    throw new Meteor.Error(404, 'Something not found');

  var returnVal = SomethingService.cancel(something, reason);
  console.timeEnd('cancelSomething method'); // <--- prints "cancelSomething 350ms" or there abouts
  return returnVal;
}
```

clientSide:

```
  console.time('meteorCall');
  Meteor.call('cancelSomething', this._id, reason, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('an error occurred', err);
    }
    console.timeEnd('meteorCall'); // <--- prints "meteorCall 11500" or so
  });
```

EDIT: 
I have noticed there is some correlation with the quantity of docs within the "somethings" in the db. w/ 500 documents it takes about 1 second to receive the return on the client, with 5000 it takes about 8.5 seconds ...

Comment: 10 seconds is the default polling interval for mongo when Meteor is not running as a part of the replica set. I wonder if there is something wrong with your database setup...

Comment: @AndrewMao Good thinking with the polling, but this is a meteor method and I'm testing when the callback from the Meteor.call('cancelSomething') occurs. Method call/callback shouldnt have anything to do with reactive updates to collections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting. I think this one is hard to answer without knowing more about your app, but I have some suggestions that could help steer you in the right direction.

#### blocking

If we can assume that the timers are working properly, what *could* be happening is that the server is unable to **begin** execution of the method because another method call by the same client is already in progress. Have a look at [unblock](http://docs.meteor.com/#method_unblock) in the docs. The answer may be as simple as putting a `this.unblock` at the top of one of your methods.

#### syncing

If `SomethingService.cancel` does something which results in a lot of DDP traffic, that could tie up the client for a while and make it unable to execute your callback. For example if it:

- modified or created a lot of documents which then had to be synced to the client
- indirectly caused an expensive subscription to be rerun (my money is on this one)

---

### Updated Answer

It seems the problem had to to with a call to `observe`, which makes a lot of sense given your high CPU load. Frankly, it's a little silly that I didn't suggest this because I have already answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467545/meteor-node-process-cpu-usage-nears-100/). If you want to try to keep the observe, here are some additional suggestions:

- Use [oplog tailing](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver).
- Try to narrow the scope of the observe as much as possible using selectors which are currently supported by the oplog observe driver. The supported selectors should improve at or before meteor 1.0.
- Limit the fields to only those you need.
- Check that oplog tailing is working by adding the facts package.

Comment: I appreciate you writing back. I added this.unblock() as the first line of the method and the timing is the same. I've added additional info to the question (number of docs)

Comment: Bummer. I added another idea to the pile. Maybe if I keep guessing I'll eventually get it right. :)

Comment: I'd also bet on the expensive subscription theory.  More specifically I'd guess the cancel causes a db change which is causing an inefficient re-rendering of client side dependencies which blocks the UI thread and delays the firing of the callback.  To debug I would:  use the ddp-proxy (to rule out anything non-client), log all template render functions, and use the onInvalidate callback to trace all subscriptions.

Comment: @alanning thanks for that, i will do this when i get some time (next few days)

Comment: We eventually figured out it was to do with observers. When we commented out the observers we saw the response time come back in line with expected.  We've since started rewriting the app to use node's EventEmitter pattern instead of observers. Our app was manageable with about 1000 docs in the db, but spiked cpu to 100% with 3500 docs in the db. *shrug* maybe it will be better by 1.0.0 ?

Comment: I updated the answer with some more suggestions, if you want to try and keep the observe(s).