# Is it possible (with Meteor) to control when publications are pushed to subscribed clients?

Tags: javascript, meteor

When programming with Meteor, is it possible to control when publications are pushed (DDP update to local MiniMongo) to subscribed clients. It looks like the default behaviour is to push changes as soon as any changes to associated collections are made. In my application, this would be very inefficient and lead to many unnecessary updates.

Ideally, what I would like to do is to delay pushing changes until I have a specific change in another collection.

So, for example, if I have the following collections and associated publications and subscriptions:

```
// Client and server
Scores = new Meteor.Collection('scores');
GameState = new Meteor.Collection('gameState');

Meteor.publish('scores', function(gameId) {
    return Scores.find({id: gameId});
});

Meteor.publish('gameState', function(gameId) {
    return GameState.find({id: gameId});
});

// Client only
Meteor.subscribe('scores');
Meteor.subscribe('gameState');
```

What I'd like to do is to delay updates to clients' local 'scores' collections until the game state reaches a specific state.

Comment: It's not a complete answer, but have a look at `observeChanges()`, https://docs.meteor.com/#observe_changes - use it on the server side to populate a collection and deliver only if the required changes happened. It's a flexible but complicated framework. Also see https://www.eventedmind.com/tracks/feed-archive/meteor-observe-in-a-publish-function

Comment: I did wonder whether I could implement a work around using observeChanges() and another subscription. It would have been easier (if not necessarily the 'best' way) if I was able to avoid pushing updates on an existing publication if a flag was passed in the subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you can use a combination of an [autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun) and a session variable to trigger the subscription. Something like this:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  var gameId = Session.get('currentGame');
  if (gameId && Session.get('excitingLevel')) {
    Meteor.subscribe('scores', gameId);
    Meteor.subscribe('gameState', gameId);
  }
});
```

Here I'm using `excitingLevel` and `currentGame` (could there not be a game going on?) to activate the subscription. Also note that `autorun` is clever enough to **stop** the subscription if the conditions are no longer met. So if the player leaves the game (`Session.set('currentGame', undefined)`) or the level is no longer exciting, the subscription will end.

#### Other notes

- If the state of the game is changing very rapidly, it may me worth evaluating [streams](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/streams) rather than using collections for your game state.
- Doing some kind of [load testing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCPBGVI3PdA) may be necessary to determine which solution is best.

Comment: So, rather than trying to avoid always pushing changes from the server you are suggesting that the clients should only subscribe when they are interested in receiving updates and stop the subscription when they are not?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This will likely be the easiest solution to implement assuming you can identify the necessary conditions on the client. Its almost certainly the best solution in terms of server performance, as well. I'd recommend using an observe on the server (as @nalply suggested) only if the necessary conditions must be determined on the server. Otherwise it's hard to justify the performance penalty of the observe. For more information see my answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467545/meteor-node-process-cpu-usage-nears-100/) question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain. My only concern is still related to performance: how expensive is starting and stopping subscriptions? If I was to adopt this solution I would have clients pretty regularly starting and stopping subscriptions.

Comment: Regularly starting and stopping subscriptions is completely normal behavior for a meteor app, and the inherent expense associated with this is low. However you still have to transmit the data to the client, so this may not be the best solution if your subscriptions have lots of documents, and were being started and stopped multiple times a second. I put some additional notes in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

In server side code publish `scores` more or less like this:

```
GameState = new Meteor.Collection('gameState')

/* Publish a custom Scores collection */
Meteor.publish("scores", function () {
  var self = this

  gameStateCursor = GameState.find();
  observerHandle = gameStateCursor.observe({
    added: function (document, index) {
      /* This is called whenever a new document is added to the game state. */

      if (/* gameState ready to publish to scores */)
        self.changed("scores", scoreId, scoreData)

      /* or use self.added() */
    },
    /* more functions as described in publish() */

  }
}
```

This not a complete answer, but a rough outline. This `observe()` framework is very crudely powerful, but low-level. Almost everything is possible. I could imagine to publish a Fourier transform of wave data with `observe()`, it's this crazy powerful.

Please read carefully https://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish, https://docs.meteor.com/#publish_added, and below (added, changed and removed).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer. So, in this example we (the server) are in control of how often updates are pushed to subscribers of the 'scores' publication? Changes are only pushed when we call self.changed()/updated() etc?

Comment: Correct! You see in the counts-by-room publish example at http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish (scroll down to see the larger code example), that they publish a derived collection, namely the counts by room.