# High CPU Utilization for Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, meteor, forever

[image]

A meteor.js 0.82 app is running on an Ubuntu 14.04 server with 2GB memory and 2 cpu cores. It was deployed using `mup`. However the CPU utilization is very high, `htop` reports `2.72` load average.

**Question:** How do I find out which part of the app is causing such a high CPU utilization? I used Kadira but it does not reveal anything taking up alot of CPU load afaik.

Does Meteor only use a single core?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: are you running your app from a bundle or with `meteor run`?

Comment: @imslavko I'm running from a bundle. The bundle was created and uploaded using `mup`.

Comment: to answer one of your questions: yes, meteor utilizes only one core, because it is all node.js

Comment: Why are there 6 mongo processes?

Comment: @AndrewMao I'm not sure why there are 6. I restarted `mongod` and it's still 6. I'm using mongodb v2.6.3

Comment: @Nyxynyx Were any of the links from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467545/meteor-node-process-cpu-usage-nears-100) helpful? Specifically, do you have [oplog tailing](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver) enabled?

Comment: @DavidWeldon Thank you, enabling oplog tailing made a huge difference.  I do notice the memory usage creeping up from 300MB to 700MB over time, is there a memory leak of some sort?

Comment: @Nyxynyx Unfortunately that one will be harder to diagnose. The only one I had was with PWR as mentioned in my answer above. It could be a library you are using, it would be that you are using `observe` when you could have used `observeChanges`, it could be that you are storing some global state on the server... hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: @DavidWeldon The app is using `observeChanges` on the clientside and doing something on the `added` event. Other than that, the server does some data processing every minute and insert records to mongo.

Comment: @Nyxynyx, an important metric when it comes to cpu usage is the number of observers. You should aim for high observer reuse. You may also look into subscription manager package and cache some subscriptions which also decreases cpu usage.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem before with Meteor 0.8.2-0.8.3. Here are what I have done to reduce the CPU usage, hope you may find it useful.

- double check your functions, ensure all function has proper `return`, and does properly catch errors
- try to use a replicaSet and oplog [mongo convert  standalone to replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/)
- write scripts to auto kill and resprawn a node process if it exceeds 100% cpu usage
- utilize multi-core capability by starting 2 processes (*edit* you have done already) and configure and setup load-balance and reverse proxy
- make sure to review your publish and subscription and limit what data to be sent to client (simply avoid something like `Collection.find();`)

Personally I recommend [Phusion Passenger](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger:-Meteor-tutorial), it makes deploying Meteor applications an ease, and I have used it for several projects without any major problems.

One more thing, avoid running the processes in *root* (or privilege user), you should be running your apps in another user like *www-data*. This is for obvious security reason.

P.S. and multiple mongo processes showing in htop are threads under a master process, you can view it in tree mode by pressing `F5`.