# Scaling Meteor (Q from Non-Technical Person)

Tags: javascript, meteor, scaling, prototyping

TL;DR is it unwise to build a web app using Meteor as our full-stack framework when expecting lots of concurrent users at scale?

We are looking to build a web app that in its first phase, is a [product hunt](http://www.producthunt.com) for music (feeding user submitted URL's from Youtube's API for play requests).

The benefits of Meteor seem to how quick it is to develop an MVP/prototype for learning about user behavior, but the risk seems to be in banking on using what is built during this phase throughout the course of the products life.

Wondering if anyone can help my ignorant brain understand in laymen's terms if anything I've asserted above is incorrect/correct, and if so, why? Sincerely grateful for any/all input on this

Answer (score 2):

The communication and CPU overhead for a meteor app without accounts or subscriptions is nearly zero. However, as I point out in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467545/meteor-node-process-cpu-usage-nears-100), the real resource constraints come from maintaining query result sets between the server and the clients. In other words, scaling becomes hard as subscriptions increase in number, size, and complexity.

Without knowing more about your product and how it works, my general recommendation is this: go for it, because meteor is going to give you a quick MVP. If you find you have a difficult time scaling because of a massive onslaught of users (congrats!), then you can always reduce your subscription expense by using a variety of tricks including non-reactive data (method calls).

Recommended reading: [Scaling Meteor: The Challenges of Real-time Apps](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/scaling-meteor-the-challenges-of-realtime-apps/)

Comment: "There isn't anything inherent to meteor that would cause scalability issues if you take the perspective that, at it's core, meteor just bundles js and css, and serves them to a client. This by itself can scale massively even on a single instance." - well the fact the client and server talk a lot and the client commonly runs server commands is one such issue.

Comment: Not saying that meteor doesn't scale, but that when addressing a question about it scaling - it's probably a good idea to address these concerns rather than claim they do not exist.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that the communication and CPU overhead for an app w/o accounts and subscriptions is near 0, however the overhead for an app with numerous and complex subscriptions can be significant. The goal is to launch and find where you can be on that continuum.

Comment: Then you might want to say that in the answer, something like "The overhead for an app without accounts or subscriptions is nearly zero" with a "This is typically a overhead you'd pay for accounts, subscriptions and live updates when not using meteor anyway, only meteor optimizes this for you in this and that case". Or something along those lines.

Comment: This is another of those arguments that weakens a concern by pointing out that the bottleneck is elsewhere, in this case minimizing developer resources instead of the usual machine resources. It addresses the question, although it does not answer it. I think it is valuable advice.

Comment: It might be clearer to warn about the spectrum of differently performing apps at the start of the answer. And that this advice only really applies to people doing a first write, not those doing a rewrite. I agree that optimisations could be applied later in many cases.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can provide a better answer given that the original question is opinion-based and lacks details. I'm starting to regret not voting to close this. Perhaps I should make my answer a wiki.

Comment: @davidweldon thanks for your input. your answer gave a lot for us to think about it. Sorry about the ambiguity of the question. Without going into too much detail, at scale a large amount  of concurrent sessions would have users posting, commenting, playing dynamically changing playlists of music, organized in post lists as described similar to Product Hunt. So the amount and complexity of subscriptions and live updates will theoretically be high relative to the amount of simultaneous users. After researching this, I feel more confident moving forward with Meteor now.

Answer (score 1):

Not unwise at all. There's a website called [ClassCraft](http://classcraft.com) built using Meteor, that I think gets 15,000 logins a day.

Your easiest solution would probably be to go with a Node-based hosting service such as [Modulus](http://modulus.io) which will handle scaling automatically for you.

The next step towards a more DIY solution would be to just host your MongoDB on a provider such as [Compose](http://compose.io) or [MongoLab](http://mongolab.com), but host the Meteor app itself on your own server(s). Look into [mup](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) for a simple deployment script, or Arunoda's newer solution he's working on, [mupx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mupx), which uses Docker to deploy Meteor apps.

This just scratches the surface, but hopefully gives you a little more confidence that it has been done and it *can* be done.