# Profiling packages and services for meteor apps

Tags: node.js, meteor, profiling, performance-testing

How can I easily profile my meteor app without filling the code with console.logs or console.time. Their is an old discussion on this ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402344/how-to-use-profilers-with-meteor](https://stackoverflow.com)), but the mentioned packages and services are all outdated.

Comment: I think this question is best suited to be asked on the Meteor Forums (forums.meteor.com) or their community slack or discord. Looking forward to see you there :-)