# Using socket.io package on Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor

We have two completely different projects. One built with nodejs and the other using Meteor. I'm handling the Meteor project and I need a certain data from the nodejs project (Which is using socket.io). Provided that I'm not allowed to modify any of the nodejs project code, I need to communicate with it using only socket.io.

I did install the socket.io package correctly via npm and I want to fully test first if I can connect before diving into the real coding.

Here's my attempt:

```
var Websocket = Npm.require('socket.io');
var socket = Websocket.connect('http://10.10.10.10:80'); // Sample IP

if (Meteor.isClient) {

    socket.on('message', function(res){
        console.log(res);
    });

    Template.hello.greeting = function () {
        return "Test";
    };

    Template.hello.events({
        'click input' : function () {
            // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
            if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
                console.log("You pressed the button");
        }
    });
}
```

Upon starting up the server, I encountered this error:

```
=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
=> Modified -- restarting.
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/vendor/web-socket-js/sample.html:5: bad f                                    ormatting in HTML template
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/examples/fileapi/public/index                                    .html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/examples/serverstats-express_                                    3/public/index.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/examples/serverstats/public/i                                    ndex.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js/README.html:1: bad for                                    matting in HTML template
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/policyfile/doc/index.html:1: bad formatting in HTML template
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js/test/beautify.js:1:15:                                     Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js/test/testparser.js:1:1                                    5: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js/tmp/embed-tokens.js:1:                                    15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js/tmp/test.js:1:15: Unex                                    pected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/diff_multi_bench_output.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGA                                    L
```

I can't interpret the given error. How can I fix this?

Last thing, the connection will be 2-way. I should be sending and receiving data. How can I make this work?

Comment: where is your node_modules directory? I believe it should *not* be in your meteor directory. You can put it one up and the package will still be found, or install socket.io globally (`npm install -g`).

Comment: please separate out your second question. It is easy to miss and somewhat unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have installed the package right in your meteor project directory, i.e., you now have a node_modules directory in your meteor directory. Remember that meteor will read *all* subdirectories other than a few special ones (private, ..?), and will try to make the html files available as templates and load all the js files. The package you installed clearly has a lot more than the library itself, and those other files confuse meteor.

To solve this, just move your node_modules directory one up, or install the packages you need globally (`npm install -g`).

Also see this: [How do we or can we use node modules via npm with Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165978/how-do-we-or-can-we-use-node-modules-via-npm-with-meteor)