# Load NPM package in Meteor 1.0?

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

With the official launch of Meteor, is there a solid way to use NPM packages? I'm trying to use embed.ly but I don't see any straightforward way to do so.

Also, as a meteor novice, how do I include packages in my files? I don't see any 'require' or 'exports' functions.

Thanks!

Comment: When you add a Meteor package to your app, its exports are automatically accessible in your JS files. No need to use require.

Comment: I'd hate to close a Meteor question, but this is an exact duplicate of [How do we or can we use node modules via npm with Meteor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165978/how-do-we-or-can-we-use-node-modules-via-npm-with-meteor)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install `meteorhacks:npm`

```
meteor add meteorhacks:npm
meteor
```

Meteor will then stop. You can then edit the new package.json file

```
{
    "request" : "2.33.0"
}
```

Then when you start Meteor it will install the npm modules for you.

Usage would as follows (use `Meteor.npmRequire` instead of `require`)

```
request = Meteor.npmRequire("request");
```

Comment: It's worth noting that Meteor.npmRequire is server side only. https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm

Comment: hi there, thank you for the answer! I'm now running into some problems with using the JSFTP module in particular. I have a question here, I'd appreciate it if you could give me some pointers.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822711/running-ftp-in-meteor

Comment: Also worth noting Meteor Supports this natively: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Npm-depends

Comment: @jm_____ The `meteorhacks:npm` package is actually just a proxy for Npm.depends and Npm.require. It's not straightforward to use natively as it requires you to make a package containing them, as meteorhacks:npm does without you having to write one.

Answer (score 10):

In the new "localmarket" example, they include a npm package in the package directory like this:

> Request = Meteor.wrapAsync(Npm.require('request'));

and in the package.js file:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "Wraps the request module from Npm in a fiber.",
  version: '0.0.0'
});

Npm.depends({request: "2.33.0"});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.add_files('request-server.js', 'server');
  api.export('Request');
});
```

Comment: the question wasn't about use of npm packages in meteor packages. The mechanism to use npm packages there is different from use in a meteor project itself

Comment: I agree, this seems to me the cleaner approach, because using already implemented features. Instead of adding a 3rd party package, which enables you to include npm packages through yet another config file, you can simply create your own package and define dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can install this package https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm first. Then use it to require other NPM packages.