# run Meteor client-side javascript (complete async method) before rendering

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-autoform

My meteor app interacts with a mongodb-backed node.js microservice. I want to use autoform on the meteor app without having to maintain two copies of the schemas.

The microservice schemas are mongoose but it was straighforward to write a translator for autoform's simple-schema.

Getting the translations into meteor has been the tough part.

First, I was going to use npm. That proved to be a problem because meteor/hacks can't use local (npm link'd) packages.

Then, I considered browserify. That was no good because mongoose isn't client-side compatible.

Finally, I decided to just serve up the translations with express.

The remaining issue is that I need to attach the schema with collection2 BEFORE autoform tries to render.

I put the HTTP request in a Meteor.method. How/Where do I call attachSchema() such that it occurs before rendering is attempted?

This is what I tried:

```
onBeforeAction: function () {
  var self = this;
  Meteor.call('fetchSchema', 'ModelName', function (err, schema) {
    ModelName.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema(schema));
    self.next();
  });
}
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'fetchSchema': TypeError: object is not a function
```

How should I be going about this?

Comment: You can use npm libraries in *meteor packages* that run on the server.  There are [docs on meteor packaging](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/writingpackages) and various blog tutorials.

Comment: see also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660907/load-npm-package-in-meteor-1-0

Comment: Thanks but I have the server-side down. It's client-side that is giving me trouble. (The way collection2/autoform works, the schema needs to be attached on both server and client... that's the impression I'm under anyway)

Comment: The browser is always limited by the fact that it is a browser.  Probably you need to write an API and use `Meteor.methods()` on the server and `Meteor.call()` on the client.