# meteor 1.3 - Unable to resolve some modules:"pixi.js"

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm

I am trying to use `pix.js` in `meteor 1.3`. In `atmostphere` it says:

> Use the npm version instead, i.e. meteor npm install --save pixi.js

so I install by `meteor npm install --save pixi.js` instead. but when I start up my meteor app, I get this error:

> Unable to resolve some modules:
>
> "pixi.js" in
>   /Users/xuanxi/Desktop/bitbuckets/mindbitapp13/client/detail/game.js
>   (web.browser)
>                                                  If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:
>                                                    meteor npm install --save pixi.js

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I just check and it seems like `meteor npm install` did install `pixijs` but it is in `../../../node_modules/pixi.js` folder, which is my node_module folder. is this correct? I thought it has to be specifically in meteor app folder.

Comment: I've also got same kind off issues with a lot of little package, npm doesn't seems to download all the required file to make the package work, I dunno why. I'm not sure it's a meteor related problem.

Comment: What's the `import` declaration in `game.js`?

Comment: `import PIXI from 'pixi.js';` as they suggest.

Comment: @JulienLeray [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165978/how-do-we-or-can-we-use-node-modules-via-npm-with-meteor?rq=1) might help you out, but not in my case.

Comment: @sooon Actually not. import pixi.js as suggested won't work, I suspect bad error message formulation. Meteor will tell you that each time one js file is missing on an npm module, pixi.js reference a file from on the module, not a module itself